# SQL Server Login Across LAN

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have an Access front-end on physical box A linked to a SQL Server instance in physical box A.  When I launch the FE, it automatically connects to the SQL Server database with no issue.  However, when I launch the same FE from networked physical box B,  I get a "login timeout expired" error.  I click "OK" which opens the generic SQL Server Login dialog,  I click "OK" and I'm immediately connected.  Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, first up, are you using sql logons, or windows logons?

I would on that 2nd machine re-link the tables. And you VERY much want to do make the connection with what we call a FILE dsn. If you do this, then if that instance of SQL server is open and allows incoming connections, then it should work.

So re-link the tables - in fact I recommend that you delete the table links. And AS stated you MUST use a FILE dsn - not machine/user. So, you can setup this link on the dev box that has both access + SQL server - but you REALLY need to use SQL server logons - not windows based logons.

Comment: I'm using windows logons and my app uses a connection string for "trusted" users.  I switched over to using a File DSN and ran into the same issue.  HOWEVER, I'm now receiving an error message I can work with, i.e., "Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection."  No suprise - I'm using a peer-to-peer network and the database is simply sitting in one of the laptops.  There's a bunch of things I now try.  Thanks again!

Comment: You using a domain logon system? you can't use windows logons as a connection method with JUST a local instance of sql server running on that one box. Windows auth means that their workstation logons are going to be used. And that means you have to logon to your windows domain server, and add the rights and permission to each of those users to that database. You can't control the logon/password used since that comes from the workstation. So, this means you must be able to logon to the domain server, and add these users with permissions to that database.

Comment: If you don't have a domain server to add the users and their rights to that database, then I would suggest you adopt sql server logons.  You have little luck to get windows auth working. All of the rights and setup of those users will occur 100% outside of sql server. You can as a hack create (add) those users and logons to your ONE workstation you are running - the user names + passwords will have to match 100% exact the workstation passwords.  Or maybe you REALLY are on a domain, and you are able to logon to that domain server and add user rights to that sql server instance.

Comment: so windows authenticaton means you use your network managemnt tools and the domain server to control who can use that database. If you use SQL server logons, then you only have to deal with and use SQL server logons to make this work. You can use windows authentication, but it not clear if you have the ability to log on to the domain server to setup the users rights and permissions. If you don't, then as noted, you are far better off to adopt SQL server logons - since they quite much ignore the whole windows network process of setting up users and rights.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks!